# c# stop data repeating itself in label

Tags: c#

How would i stop data repeating itself in a label?

at the moment my balance keep adding a value next to it for e.g balance: 500.000, 500.000

where i only want it to open once. here the code i am using

```
SqlDataReader readdata;

try
{

    sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Open();
    sqlCommandbalance.Parameters["@accountID"].Value = show.accountID;
    readdata = sqlCommandbalance.ExecuteReader();
    string balanceDB = null;
    string availableBalance = null;
    while (readdata.Read())
    {
        balanceDB = readdata["balance"].ToString();
        availableBalance = (Convert.ToDecimal(readdata["balance"].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(readdata["overdraftlimit"])).ToString();
    }
    sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Close();
    balanceShow.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();
    availablebalanceShow.Text += " " + availableBalance.ToString();
```

Comment: Why are you using += and appending the new value to the old Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change this:

```
balanceShow.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();
availablebalanceShow.Text += " " + availableBalance.ToString();
```

to

```
balanceShow.Text = " " + balanceDB.ToString();
availablebalanceShow.Text = " " + availableBalance.ToString();
```

the += is equivalent to saying this:

```
balanceShow.Text = balanceShow.Text + " " + balanceDB.ToString();
```

which is why it is always appending the text to the existing text.  You want to just assign the value of balance to the Text property.

Comment: how would i keep the text i have in the existing label now it shows the amount but the your balance: has disappeared

Comment: if you debug this what is the value of `balanceDB` at the point you assign it to `balanceShow.Text`?

Comment: 500.000 which is the value of balance from the database

Comment: then the problem is that you are not resetting the label between calls of this code.  Every time you call this code you are appending a new balance to the existing code in the label.  you need to clear and reset the base text in the label somewhere.  Alternatively why not just do this: `balanceShow.Text = "your balance: " + balanceDB.ToString();`?